# How to order one table by the number of foreign key values in another?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I am trying to order one table (comment_thread) by the number of individual comments in another table (comment_comment).

**comment_thread**

```
|------------|---------------|
|      id    |     obj_id    |
|------------|---------------|
|      1     |       24      |
|------------|---------------|
|      2     |       34      |
|------------|---------------|
```

**comment_comment**

```
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      id    |   thread_id   |      des      |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      1     |      24       |     test 1    |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      2     |      34       |     test 2    |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      3     |      34       |     test 3    |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      4     |      34       |     test 4    |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
|      5     |      24       |     test 8    |
|------------|---------------|---------------|
```

**Desired Output**

```
|------------|---------------|
|      id    |     obj_id    |
|------------|---------------|
|      2     |       34      |
|------------|---------------|
|      1     |       24      |
|------------|---------------|
```

**Current Query**

```
SELECT ctr.obj_id FROM
(SELECT thread_id FROM comment_comment
group by thread_id ORDER BY COUNT(thread_id) DESC) cc
LEFT JOIN comment_thread ctr ON cc.thread_id = ctr.id
```

The query does not return the comment_comment table in the correct order. Can anyone help me with this?

**Real Data Test:**

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=7cd9585fd88381818f9581d17fa338f1:

ID 119 should be first,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ORDER BY` in a subquery has no (guranteed) effect. It has to be for the outer most query.

Either use a correlated subquery in the `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT ct.id,
       ct.obj_id
       FROM comment_thread ct
       ORDER BY (SELECT count(*)
                        FROM comment_comment cc
                        WHERE cc.thread_id = ct.obj_id) DESC;
```

Or left join an aggregation and order by the joined count.

```
SELECT ct.id,
       ct.obj_id
       FROM comment_thread ct
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT cc.thread_id,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM comment_comment cc
                              GROUP BY cc.thread_id) x
                      ON x.thread_id = ct.obj_id
       ORDER BY x.count DESC
                        NULLS LAST;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am trying both the queries but I am still getting the data in the wrong order.

Comment: @RobFyffe: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=3e9e15f51a1ae894927be4305106b84a

Comment: that is strange for me when working with real data my order is wrong. See my edit.

Comment: @RobFyffe: Show a minimum input set with which the problem can be reproduced. If you like you can edit the fiddle too.

Comment: I did notice I am only getting 99 results returning. Is there a limit setting in postgres?

Comment: Ignore, there are only 99 rows, I thought there was more.

Comment: If you check the fiddle now the last query isn't in the correct order.

Comment: @RobFyffe: If a fiddle is changed you need to run it, so that a new URL is generated and then you have to post that URL.

Comment: The first suggestion is returning me the same order as I currently had with the original query I posted. Its very strange.

Comment: Ah I see, for `12` there is no corresponding data, so you have to define how `NULL`s should get sorted. With `NULLS LAST` the joined version sorts `12` last lik the subquery version does: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.4&fiddle=5c6cb991ed57e4fc15a5ef0c2a1f094c `24` and `34` both have three so they might switch positions.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I still have the same problem with real data so I am going to add many more and test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186821/discussion-between-rob-fyffe-and-sticky-bit).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @sticky-bit, your solution worked, I was just referencing the wrong column in the comparison.

**Final Query**

```
SELECT ct.id,
       ct.obj_id
       FROM comment_thread ct
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT cc.thread_id,
                              count(*) count
                              FROM comment_comment cc
                              GROUP BY cc.thread_id) x
                      ON x.thread_id = ct.id
       ORDER BY x.count DESC
                        NULLS LAST;
```